# AngularJS - hide category if item from the same not in results array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on product filter and this is what I have.

```
$scope.categories = {meat: [array of products], bread: [array of products], drinks: [array of products]}
$scope.filterQuery = '';
```

Every category has it's own "PRODUCTS" array with items. I am using ngRepeat to filter (via filterQuery) through categories and ngRepeat again so I can show products inside categories.

My question is: If I'm using input field with ngModel to provide products filtering, how can I hide categories if products from the same are not in results array?

My code inside component:

```
<div class="component-wrapper" ng-repeat="(key, data) in categories">
CATEGORY
<div class="products" ng-repeat="item in results = (data | filter: filterQuery)">Product</div>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle/plunker out of it? Not able to understand `If I'm using input field with ngModel to provide products filtering`

Comment: @tanmay Sorry if I wasn't very clear but I found the solution. Thank you for your time, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have products bound to `results`, you can check for its length at run time and hide its category using `ng-hide="results.length == 0"`

See working [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/3FpMj6YzAqNuB1Cv5QmA?p=preview)